# A coin flip's long tail

Tags: mathematics, probability, coin-tossing

I have a (possibly-) unfair coin, which lands heads with probability $p$ and lands tails with probability $1-p$. I toss it twice; the tosses are *independent* and *identically distributed*.

The probabilities of the various outcomes will vary depending on $p$. For example, if I know that $p = \frac12$, then the probability of tossing two heads, which I'll abbreviate $\mathbb P(HH)$, can be calculated as $p^2 = \frac14$. Symmetrically, the probability of tossing two tails $\mathbb P(TT) = \frac14$.

On the other hand, if I know that $p > \frac12$, e.g. $p = \frac1{\sqrt 3}$, then $HH$ becomes more likely: $\mathbb P(HH) = \frac13$. Correspondingly, $TT$ becomes less likely: $\mathbb P(TT) = (1 - \frac1{\sqrt 3})^2 \approx 0.18$.

It seems like I can push $HH$ up above $\frac14$, but only by pushing $TT$ down below that same number. With that in mind, the following question might seem surprising:

> **Under what circumstances does $\mathbb P(HH) = \mathbb P(TT) = \frac13$?**

Comment: Is this a trick question? Your statement "the tosses are independent and identically distributed" makes it mathematically impossible to have both probabilities equal 1/3.

Comment: @Gamow: I believe my statement is accurate. This wouldn't be an interesting puzzle if it weren't for the apparent contradiction :)

Comment: I'll think about how to give subtle hints if no-one has got closer to the answer by tomorrow.

Comment: Must the coin have two faces, one with a single head and the other with a single tail?

Comment: Yes. (Actually, until you mentioned it I didn't deeply think about how you'd even go about weighting a coin to change the outcome of its probabilities. Probably the actual easiest thing would be to put a bunch of heads and tailses on a die and weight that appropriately. But that's irrelevant to the puzzle: from the puzzle's perspective the only thing that matters is that there are exactly two possible outcomes of each individual coin toss.)

Comment: Why do I get the feeling that $i$ is going to make an appearance in the answer...

Comment: Are you only tossing the coin twice?

Comment: @BenMillwood Quantum-mechanical coins? In a Bose-Einstein model, there are only three possible states... however, I hope this is not the answer.

Comment: Does the answer involve learning that TH or HT is not the flip result?

Comment: I feel like this could be done with magnets somehow - each coin contains a magnet, one with north on H, one on T, and the table has a randomly chosen magnetic field that has a 50% (?) chance to flip a coin that lands with its opposite magnetic charge facing down.  Need to check the math on that...

Comment: So, just to clarify, is the remaining probability (1/3) the probability of P(HT) + P(TH)?  Also, are we to assume that the coin cannot land on it's edge?

Comment: @Aprough - if P(H) is p and P(T) is 1-p, then it must be one of those results, thus no edge landings.

Comment: I only toss the coin twice, $i$ doesn't appear, there's no quantum involved, $\mathbb P(TH) = \mathbb P(HT) = 1/6$, no magnets, no edge. The question was inspired by me investigating an entirely natural mathematical phenomenon that you might reasonably encounter under normal circumstances, and noting a surprising result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$p$ is a random variable, chosen with uniform probability over the interval [0,1]. The probability of two heads is $\int_0^1 p^2=\frac{1}{3}$, and by symmetry so is the probability of two tails.

Comment: Now that I think about it this makes perfect sense. There was definitely a reason why Ben Millwood said the flips were _identically distributed_.

Comment: Also explains why they are *possibly* unfair.

Comment: Of course, this destroys independence, though. In this case, the flips are only *conditionally* independent, conditional on the value of $p$.

Comment: @user2357112: How so? The outcome of the first flip still has no bearing on the probability of the second flip.

Comment: @orp: Independence is not about causation. If you know that the first flip is H, you know that $p$ is more likely to be high than low, and thus, you know that the second flip is more likely to be H too. It doesn't matter that the two flips don't affect each other.

Comment: @user2357112: If $p$ is 0.1 and you happen flip heads, you may conclude that it's more likely that $p$ is high. But it isn't actually: it's 0.1. Independence is about whether the occurrence of an event influences the probability of another event, which isn't the case here.

Comment: @orp: No, it's about whether one event *tells you something* about another event. Also, you can't just suddenly fix $p$ like that. Let me put it this way. Let $H?$ be the event that the first coin lands heads, and let $?H$ be the event the second coin lands heads. In the sample space of all possible values of $p$, flip 1, and flip 2, $p(H?) = 1/2$ and $P(HH) = 1/3$, so $P(?H|H?) = P(HH)/P(H?) = (1/3)/(1/2) = 2/3 \ne P(?H)$. Thus, by the definition of independence, $?H$ and $H?$ are not independent.

Comment: @user2357112 agreed, it doesn't preserve independence; that's ruled out by the fact that they have identical probabilities. Given that, I went for an answer which preserves conditional independence.

Comment: This was the answer that I had in mind, but I'm willing to conceded that @user2357112 seems to have a point. I should perhaps have been more careful what I meant by "independent": indeed I meant only to say that there was no causal relationship between the outcome of the coin tosses, but I guess I'm so used to saying i.i.d. that I slipped and accidentally said something too precise. Sorry about that :)

Comment: (I actually had in mind where $p$ is unknown, and I have a uniform prior, and I intended that phrasing like "if I know $p = 1/2$" was meant to cue that a tiny bit. I suppose this also motivated the independence, because the coin flips really are independent to the person who knows $p$. But, to that person, the probabilities aren't $1/3$, so that's no real excuse!)

Comment: @user2357112: OK, I now see that the math works out. I didn't think that was the case. You were confusing me by essentially telling me that independence is not when the occurrence of an event impacts the probability of another (which _was_ in fact the case here). Anyway, let's not argue in the comments... that's not the point of comments.

Comment: [A generalization to n coins.](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/8000/4551)

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be mathematically impossible. The probability of two heads is $1/3$ and the probability of two tails is $1/3$.

Since they're equal, this gives us
$$
p^2 = (1-p)^2
$$
$$
p = 1-p
$$
$$
p = 1/2
$$

But $(1/2)^2 = 1/4$, not $1/3$.

If there really is a solution to this I'd be really interested to see it.

Comment: I agree that it *seems* impossible, but I insist that it is not!

Comment: @Ben Millwood Just to clarify that this isn't a trick question, are you insisting that it is mathematically possible to answer the question, or that it is mathematically possible for P(HH) = P(TT) = 1/3? If this is the dirty trick I'm suspecting, "Under no circumstances" is a potentially valid answer.